# How to solve Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

```
path='Precios horarios mercado diario en España'
ficheros <- dir(paste(path,'/marginalpdbc_2020_2022/',sep=''))
dat2022 = as.data.frame(matrix(0,length(ficheros),25)) #matriz(valores,nfilas,ncolumnas) 
colnames(dat2022) = c("Fecha",c(1:24)) 

for (i in 1:length(ficheros)){ 
  
  #lectura - dat es arreglando datos de cada fichero concreto
  dat <-read.csv(paste(path,'/marginalpdbc_2020_2022/',substr(ficheros[i],1,21),'.csv',sep=''),sep=';',header=FALSE)
  dat = as.data.frame(dat)
  dat=dat[c(-1,-length(dat[,1])),c(-length(dat[1,])+2,-length(dat[1,]))] ....
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: cannot open file 'Precios horarios mercado diario en España/marginalpdbc_2020_2022/NA.csv/NA.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

```
Warning: cannot open file 'Precios horarios mercado diario en España/marginalpdbc_2020_2022/NA.csv/NA.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Simply put, your `path` object doesn't appear correct.

Comment: how could I correct it?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what files exist and what files you are trying to read. It seems you already found the file names so I'm not sure why the `substr()` part is there. What about just `read.csv(ficheros[i],sep=';',header=FALSE)` if you also do `ficheros <- dir(paste(path,'/marginalpdbc_2020_2022/',sep=''), full.names=TRUE)`